# Problema con paginación por medio de ajax, botones no reaccionan después del primer uso

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, paginación

Tengo un sitio de noticias donde se despliegan tarjetas paginadas al inicio, este es el codigo php con el que traigo los datos y le doy formato:

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';
$paginaActual = isset($_GET['pagina']) ? $_GET['pagina']:1;
$numeroNoticias = 5;
$inicio = ($paginaActual-1)*$numeroNoticias;
$noticias = mysqli_query($enlace,"SELECT n.*,c.nombreUsuario FROM noticias n JOIN cuentasusuarios c ON c.idUsuario = n.idUsuario LIMIT $inicio,$numeroNoticias");
if(mysqli_num_rows($noticias)>0){
    while($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($noticias)){
        echo '<section class="d-md-flex muestraNoticia mb-1 mt-1 ">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-5 me-3">
                    <div class="imagenNoticia h-100">
                        <img src="'.$fila['imgPortada'].'" alt="" class="img-fluid h-100">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-7 p-2">
                    <a><h1 class="tituloNoticia">'.$fila['titulo'].'</h1></a>
                    <a><h2 class="nombreAutor">'.$fila['nombreUsuario'].'</h2></a>
                    <a><h2 class="categoriaNoticia">Categoria</h2></a>
                    <a><h2 class="diaNoticia">'.$fila['fechaHora'].'</h2></a>
                </div>
            </section>';
    }
}

$noticiasTotales = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($enlace,"SELECT * FROM noticias"));
$numPaginas = ceil($noticiasTotales/$numeroNoticias);
for($i=1; $i <= $numPaginas; $i++){
    echo '<a type="button" class="pagina ms-1 me-1" data-pagina="'.$i.'" >'.$i.'</a>';
}
```

?>

en ese código al final también se asigna los botones de cada página, para mostrarlas en mi página uso xhr para hacer un llamado para que no se este recargando la página cada vez que se le da clic a un boton, el detalle es que después de presionar o de mandar a llamar el xhr por primera vez los botones se quedan sin función, aquí esta el código javascript:

```
var paginas = document.getElementsByClassName("pagina");
var contenedorNoticias = document.getElementById("contenedorNoticias");
var xhr;
for(let i=0;i<paginas.length;i++){
    paginas[i].addEventListener("click",(pagina)=>{
        pagina.preventDefault();
        var paginaActual = pagina.target.getAttribute("data-pagina");
        console.log(pagina.target.getAttribute("data-pagina"));
        if(xhr){
            xhr.abort();
        }
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
                contenedorNoticias.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            }
        }
        xhr.open("GET","/php/muestraArticuloIndex.php?pagina="+paginaActual);
        xhr.send();
        console.log("2");
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    })
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",()=>{
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
                contenedorNoticias.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            }
        }
        xhr.open("GET","/php/muestraArticuloIndex.php?pagina=1");
        xhr.send();
        console.log(xhr);
})
```

El primer bloque define que pasa cuando se da click en cualquiera de los botones de la páginación, mientras que el segundo es para cuando se carga por primera vez la página, en este caso por ejemplo despues de que carga la página los botones no sirven, puse unos cuantos log adentro para ver si hacian algo pero no esta llamando el listener, cuando pongo el include php en el div donde va mi xhr me deja presionar el boton pero solo 1 vez, despues se vuelve a bloquear, la verdad soy nuevo en esto de ajax y no encuentro cual es la falla 7u7